# смена цвета шрифта в фиксированном меню в зависимости от фона блока над которым меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

на сайте https://xn----8sbbqciguqh1bit.xn--p1ai/ есть фиксированное меню оно белого цвета на если меню над блоком с белым фоном его не видно, как сделать что бы меню меняло цвет в зависимости над каким блоком он находиться

Comment: Оно же на черном фоне шапки всегда...?

Comment: черный фон меню уберем

Comment: [Тут](https://webformyself.com/avtomaticheskaya-css-inversiya-cveta-teksta-v-zavisimosti-ot-fona/) подробно описано